# How to redirect non www to www using htaccess in wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this both url http://example.com/robots.txt and  http://example.com/sitemap.xml to http://www.example.com/robots.txt and  http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml.

Also I have also redirected my http://example.com to http://www.example.com but sitemap and robots open in both url (non www) and (www) so I only want that it only open in www format.

I tried using below code

```
RewriteRule sitemap\.xml  http://example.com/sitemap. [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml [L,R=301]
```

But didnt work for me please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first redirect rule is wrong. Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt)$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```